# GameCenter Displaying a Leaderboard Set

Tags: swift, ios8, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am having difficulties getting my leaderboard sets to display. Not sure if it is possible, but so far I am not able to get it working.

For some background, I have levels in my game and within each level I have 3 scoring metrics, so I have a leaderboard set for each level.

For example:

```
Level 1 Leaderboard Set
    |----- Level 1 Points Leaderboard
    |----- Level 1 Average Time Leaderboard
    |----- Level 1 Best Time Leaderboard
```

When the level is complete, I want to display the Level 1 Leaderboard set and not an individual leaderboard. So far no go.

Here is the code:

```
var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
gc.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
gc.leaderboardIdentifier = boardid
self.presentViewController(gc, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

where `boardid` is the id of the `leaderboard` set.

Comment: I also want to know this, ever solved it?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to solve it. I just have to display the leaderboard individually and not the entire set. Really is a bummer.

Comment: Me neither. However, by not setting leaderboardIdentifier it will bring up a list of all the sets. Not exactly what I wanted but better than an individual leaderboard.

Answer (score 1):

You must make boardid a string. Put quotations around boardid

```
gc.leaderboardIdentifier = "boardid" //Put quotations
```

Hope this helped!